# Performing a search through database for value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use a search bar, to search for values in my Firebase Database. For example:

```
---users---
     |
     | ---1412512351--     
     |   |
     |   |- name: Nick
     |   |- age: 37
     |
     | ---5734739374--
     |   |
     |   |- name: John
     |   |- age: 19
```

When the user finishes typing, and clicks done, I want to perform a search through the database and find the name that they are looking for. Instead of loading all of the users, which could take a while.

Also, I want to get all of the values close to the search. For example if it type "Nick", It should bring up a values close to that string, like Nicholas or Nathan etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a particular user (in JS):

```
var usersRef = new Firebase("https://yourdb.firebaseio.com/users/");
var theNameIAmAfter = usersRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo(SearchByThisName);
```

> Also, I want to get all of the values close to the search. For example
>   if it type "Nick", It should bring up a values close to that string,
>   like Nicholas or Nathan etc...

I'm not sure if that's doable with firebase.

Comment: how would you test if it found a user, like would there be a handler that after you searched it would say if it was there or not?

Comment: Firebase will return an object anyway but it gives you two important variables `$resolved` and `$id`. So to answer your question, using the example above, add a condition like so: `theNameIAmAfter.$id == "undefined"`

Comment: so like  `print(nameImAfter.$id)` ??

Comment: No that would print "undefined"

Comment: Try printing a firebase object and see what it returns, you'll find that in addition to the data itself you'll get `$id`, `$resolved` and other variables, if `$id` is `undefined` then this means the data you're after doesn't exist in the database.